# Any total order on $X$ is maximal element

Tags: order-theory

Let $X$ be a non-empty set and $R$ be the set of partial orders on $X$.

(1) Show that $R$ is partially ordered by inclusion $\subset$.

(2) Show that any total order on $X$ is a maximal element in $(R, \subset)$

Comment: Which part did you find difficult? This is rather straightforward to show both of these.

Comment: The 2nd part. Since the definition for $R_1$ to be 'maximal' is if $R_1 \subset R_2$, then $R_1 = R_2$. It looks very obvious that no partial order can extend a total order. But I'm not sure how to formally show this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** Suppose that $R_1$ is a total order, and $R_2$ extends it, then for some $(x,y)\in R_2$ we have that $(x,y)\notin R_1$. Use the fact that $R_1$ is total, and arrive at a contradiction to the antisymmetry of $R_2$.

Comment: We have that the relation $x \leq y$ is not in $R_1$. Because $R_1$ is total, we must have $x \geq y$. But how would this be a contradiction?

Comment: In other words, why cant we have $x = y$ in $R_2$ and only have $x \leq y$ in $R_1$? With that, $R_2$ would extend $R_1$. Thanks.

Comment: No, since $(x,y)\notin R_1$ it follows that $x\neq y$ (since $(x,x)\in R_1$).

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Can you elaborate a bit on this?  When you say $(x,y)$, did you mean $x leq y$ or any relation between $x$ and $y$? Also, how would having $x = x$ in $R_1$ make $x = y$ impossible?

Comment: What is $\leq$? Do you remember what the definition of a relation is?

Comment: A relation is a subset of $X \cross Y$. I was looking at the definition of partial order, and got confused by $=$.

Comment: So why would $(x,x) \in R_1$ make $x \neq y$?

Comment: What did we assume on $(x,y)$?

Comment: So because we assume $(x,y)$ is not in $R_1$, and $R_1$ is total, we must have $(y,x)$ in $R_2$. Then we have  $x = y$ in $R_2$. Since we have $(x,x)$ in $R_1$, we know $x \neq y$ in $R_1$. This makes the relation of $x$ and $y$ disagree on $R_1$ and $R_2$? Am I interpretating your argument correct? Thanks

Comment: No. You're just piling on most of my comments in hope that this argument makes sense. But it doesn't. Take a break from this exercise. Then when you are back, write down *all* the definitions relevant here: what it means being a partial order, total order, etc. then write down the assumptions from my hint, and the additional hint from my previous comments. Then the argument will be clear.